# Passing boxed trait object to function accepting generic parameter implementing the trait

Tags: rust

I have a function which returns a boxed trait object, and another function that accepts a reference to an object implementing the same trait. I would like to pass a reference to the boxed trait object to the second function, but I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Example simplified code:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("A");
    }
}

struct B {}

impl MyTrait for B{
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("B");
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

fn create_object(my_enum: MyEnum) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    let boxed_value: Box<dyn MyTrait> = match my_enum {
        MyEnum::A => Box::new(A{}),
        MyEnum::B => Box::new(B{}),
    };
    boxed_value
}

fn do_something<T: MyTrait>(obj: &T) {
    obj.foo();
}

fn main() {
    use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    do_something(boxed_value.borrow_mut());
}
```

The error I get:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src\main.rs:42:5
   |
42 |     do_something(boxed_value.borrow_mut());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ------------------------ this method call resolves to `&mut Borrowed`
   |     |
   |     cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the function `do_something`
```

Intuitively, I would have hoped that in this case Rust would use dynamic dispatch and wouldn't care about the concrete type T (similarly to what happens in C++ when you pass a reference to a base class), but this seems not to be the case.

How do I pass a reference to the boxed trait object (`Box<dyn MyTrait>`) to the second function (`do_something`)? Is this possible in some way? A solution requiring a change to `do_something` would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Intuitively, I would have hoped that in this case Rust would use dynamic dispatch and wouldn't care about the concrete type T (similarly to what happens in C++ when you pass a reference to a base class), but this seems not to be the case.

You can make that happen with a cast (or just type ascription, eventually) and by relaxing the default requirement for `T` to be `Sized`:

```rust
fn do_something<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(obj: &T) {
    obj.foo();
}
```

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
do_something(boxed_value.borrow() as &dyn MyTrait);
```

But if you’re not otherwise using `T`, you can opt into dynamic dispatch on the function side much more simply:

```rust
fn do_something(obj: &dyn Borrow) {
    obj.foo();
}
```

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
do_something(boxed_value.borrow());
```

And if you don’t care that `obj` is a borrow and want to leave the option of static dispatch open, you can implement `MyTrait` for `&dyn MyTrait`:

```rust
impl MyTrait for &dyn MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) {
        (*self).foo();
    }
}
```

```rust
fn do_something<T: MyTrait>(obj: T) {
    obj.foo();
}

// or, again, if not otherwise using T:

fn do_something(obj: impl MyTrait) {
    obj.foo();
}
```

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
do_something(boxed_value.borrow());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to unbox the value
you can instead implement `MyTrait` on `Box<dyn MyTrait>`
and forward to the boxed value.

```
impl MyTrait for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        self.deref().foo()
    }
}
```

Then you don't even need to call `borrow_mut`.

```
fn main() {
    use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    do_something(&boxed_value);
}
```

There's a working example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=037ab3f64b1b1b0984612c5803e00cbd)

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you'll need to add `?Sized` to the trait bound in `do_something`, and then I think you have one of three options:

1. (Least general) Use `as_ref()` on the `Box` when you call `do_something`.

```rust
fn do_something<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(obj: &T) {
    obj.foo();
}

fn main() {
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    do_something(boxed_value.as_ref());
}
```

2. (Most general) Replace the type of `obj` in `do_something` with `impl AsRef<T>`. This will make `do_something` work with anything convertible to a `&T`.

```rust
fn do_something<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(obj: impl AsRef<T>) {
    obj.as_ref().foo();
}

fn main() {
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    do_something(boxed_value);
}
```

3. (Medium general) Replace the type of `obj` in `do_something` with `impl Deref<Target=T>`. This will make `do_something` work with any smart pointer holding a `T` (which is a bit more restrictive than `AsRef<T>` — a type can implement `AsRef<T>` for as many values of `T` as it wants, but only gets to have one `Deref` implementation).

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

fn do_something<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(obj: impl Deref<Target=T>) {
    obj.deref().foo();
}

fn main() {
    let boxed_value = create_object(MyEnum::A);
    do_something(boxed_value);
}
```